# sed regex, work on substrings and not on whole line

Tags: regex, sed, substring

suppose to have the following string:

```
commandone{alpha} commandtwo{beta} {gamma}commandthree commandtwo{delta}
```

and I want to abtain:

```
commandone{alpha} beta {gamma}commandthree delta
```

well I'm triying with regex and sed, I can easily find if is it present the pattern I look for
/commandtwo{.*}/ but not erasing commandtwo and the following two brakets. A way would be to work only the substrings "*commandtwo{beta}*" and "*commandtwo{delta}*" but I don't know even if is it possible or noto using sed.

I'm looking for a regex to perform the action I've described.
thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
sed 's/commandtwo{\([^}]*\)}/\1/g' inputfile
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'commandone{alpha} commandtwo{beta} {gamma}commandthree commandtwo{delta}'|sed 's/commandtwo{\([^}]*\)}/\1/g'
commandone{alpha} beta {gamma}commandthree delta
```

Answer (score 0):

use awk

```
$ s="commandone{alpha} commandtwo{beta} {gamma}commandthree commandtwo{delta}"
$ echo "$s" | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/commandtwo/){ gsub(/commandtwo|{|}/," ",$i)} }1'
commandone{alpha}   beta  {gamma}commandthree   delta
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want to strip all references to commandtwo from your code (but not it's arguments) probably somthing like `/commandtwo{(.*?)}/\1`